# How to generate multiple text box then insert in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in my system. I need to multiply text box then insert in one column using concatenation in mysql. I use Php in my system. Specifically my source code are the ff:

This is the index

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample Text</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="phpfunctionshandle.php" method="post" name="phpfunctionshandle"> 

        <input type="number" name="text" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit"value="Register">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset"value="cancel">Cancel</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" >
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is the handle for the index

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="handlefinal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="phpfunctionshandle"> 
<?php
include('config.php');
$text =$_POST['text'];
for ($x = 1; $x <= $text; $x++) { // I use for loop to multiple text box
    echo '<input type="text" name="sample value=""/>';
}

?>
 <button type="submit" name="submit"value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 <button type="reset"value="cancel" class="btn btn-success">Cancel</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" >
 </form>
 <Form name="handlefinal">
 <?php
include('config.php');
 $sample=$_POST['sample"'.$text.'"'];
$query = "INSERT INTO sample (text) VALUES ('$sample')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo'success';

 ?>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I use for loop to multiple the text box base on what I input on the index. For example I enter 3 in the input type number in the index.php, the text box will multiply into 3. My desired result is to query the 3 multiplied textbox.
If I enter sample1 in the first text box, and sample2 on second, and sample3 on third. The desired Output in Database in column text should be 
sample1, sample2, sample3. I try this but it turns out the last value of text box only inserted in database. In short only sample3. I don't know how to query and how to solve this. Any suggestions? and sorry for posting all my source code. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You're missing a quote `"` here: `echo '<input type="text" name="sample value=""/>';`. Should be `echo '<input type="text" name="sample" value=""/>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- You give all your inputs the same name, so only the value of the last one will get through to the server. You can solve this using an array in your form that will convert to an array for your `$_POST` variable:
  `echo '<input type="text" name="sample[]" />';`
- I am not a fan of putting the input of multiple text inputs in one database field, but if you must, you can concatenate the values when you get them from the form:
  `$samples = implode(',', $_POST['sample']);    // separated by comma`
- You should not use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` if you don't post any files.
- You have an sql injection problem. You should switch to another database interface as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and use a prepared statement.

Comment: tnx guys for all your help ok I will try again